# 古いRaspbianのraspividについて質問です。

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

私は今わけあって古いバージョンのRaspbianを使用しています。
バージョンは2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbianです。
そして、使用機器はRaspberry pi1です。

質問はraspividを使用するとなぜraspivid: command not foundとでるのかです。
新しいバージョンでは標準でraspividは入っていますし、使えるものと思っていたのですが、なぜ使えないのでしょうか？
カメラモジュールは指定の場所に挿してあります。

もしやと思う点は、新しいバージョンではカメラモジュールの使用を許可する項目がraspi-configにありますが、2012-12-16のバージョンにはなかったのでこれが原因なのでしょうか？
どうしてもこのバージョンでやる必要があるため、問題を解決したいので力を貸して欲しいです。

現状は変にいじってバージョンが変わって欲しくないため、updateもupgradeを行っていません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi のカメラモジュールが発売されたのは2013年5月ですので、
2012年末ですとたぶん開発中という時期ではないかと思います。
https://techcrunch.com/2013/05/15/pi-camera-on-sale/

2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian をインストールしてみましたが、
お気づきの通りraspi-configにカメラの設定は存在しません。

2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian のraspi-configには、「Enable Camera」という設定があります。
そのひとつ前は2013-02-09-wheezy-raspbianですが、カメラの設定はありません。
2013-05-25より古いRaspbianではupdate/upgradeが必要だと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
updateやupgradeだとカーネルのバージョンがあがるってことはありますか？
なければ実行したいと思います！
あと、raspi-configにもupdateの項目があるんですが、これを実行すると何がupdateされるのか教えてもらえませんか？

Comment: バージョンが古いせいかupdateできませんでした、、、